# Bootstrapping the same app multiple times in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project where a lot of the UI elements are separate widgets that could be used multiple times on a page. One of those widgets is a shopping cart, where I have a large view (that's present on only one page) and a small view (that's present on every page).

The page where both the large and small view of the cart is visible breaks. I've narrowed it down in Angular to the fact that both apps are bootstrapped (using `angular.bootstrap()`) but two different scopes are created. This causes loading errors.

I've reproduced the situation [here](http://codepen.io/lodybo/pen/EVjqWY). Even though the apps are bootstrapped, the `$scope` of one app isn't equal to the other. This is good, but is there a way that I can reference a module in `angular.bootstrap` so that two ngApps will share the same `$scope`?

The test HTML

```
<div data-app="multipleApps">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="testVar">a</p>
    <input type="text" size="25" ng-model="testVar" />
  </div>
</div>

<div data-app="multipleApps">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="testVar">a</p>
    <input type="text" size="25" ng-model="testVar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
angular.module("testApp", []).controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.testVar = "Ready...";
});

angular.bootstrap(document.querySelectorAll("[data-app='multipleApps']")[0], ["testApp"]);
```

I already tested using the injector returned from `angular.bootstrap()`, but this raised an `a.unshift is not a function` error from AngularJS.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("[data-app='multipleApps']");

if (els.length > 1) {
  var injector = angular.bootstrap(els[0], ["testApp"]);

  for (var i = 1; i < els.length; i++) {
    angular.bootstrap(els[i], injector);
  }
}
```